# memory leak when calling an Api

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have to load a data returned from calling an API about 1000 cell into a table view if I load it into the table view without pagination does it make a memory leak??

Comment: No, loading 1000 elements from an API won't cause a memory leak. A memory leak is when you lose track of unused objects and they are still in memory but are no longer being used. Also, table views are very efficient and reuse the cells, so you won't have 1000 cells in memory.

Comment: usually any guide available on the internet explains the concept, implementation and reason behind reusing cell in table views and collection view, go check them out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refresh your memory (no pun intended) what a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) is. No, having thousands of entries in memory does not necessarily lead to memory leak (the main source of memory leaks in Swift are closures). It could, however, increase the memory pressure – which means your app could run out of free memory which could lead to unexpected behavior (iOS would notify your app in advance by calling `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` method of your view controllers).

As for `UITableView`, it only allocates memory for visible cells which is usually about 10 rows. While you scroll the table view, it would reuse those cells (it calls `prepareForReuse()` method on those cells) that disappear from the screen and repositions them so that they are displayed with new content.